# Display submenu to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website [Mawtini](https://www.mawtini.co.il) I change this website to support Arabic language (RTL)

The submenu opens to the left when it was in english, I changed it to right because of RTL concerns.

Everything is ok except the submenu, when you mouse over the first level of submenus (up & down) the submenu opens firstly to the left for milliseconds then it opens to the right

Technically, when your mouse hover the item, it shows the menu to the left, but when it remove `li` item the menu flashes (show for few milliseconds) to the right.

What should I do to remove the flashed submenu to the right?

[image: RTL Image support]

Comment: can you provide some html an css code

Comment: there is a lot of libraries and coding, but you can inspect elements and see the effective code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is the property "transition" has in the selector .sub-menu. To works how you want, that property must be in the "sub-menu:hover" , only.

I hope it helped you.